# Why is $\Phi(x,y) = \int f(\lambda) d\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, spectral-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am reading [*Invariant Subspaces* by H. Radjavi and P. Rosenthal.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65574-6) I need help understanding the proof of Theorem $1.9$. I see why $\Phi(x,x)$ is bounded for every $x\in \mathcal H$, but how does this imply $\Phi(x,y)$ is bounded for all $x,y\in \mathcal H$?

> **Theorem.** If $f$ is a bounded, Borel measurable function on $\Bbb C$ and $E$ is a spectral measure in $\mathcal H$, then there exists a unique $A\in \mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ such that $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \int f(\lambda) d\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle$ for all $x,y\in \mathcal H$.

> *Proof.* Define $\Phi$ by $\Phi(x,y) = \int f(\lambda) d\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle$  for each fixed $x,y$. Clearly $\Phi$ is linear in $x$, and conjugate linear in $y$. Moreover, $|\Phi(x,x)| \le \|f\|_\infty\|x\|^2$. Thus, $\Phi(x,y)$ is a **bounded** bilinear functional, and therefore there is a unique $A$ such that $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \Phi(x,y)$ for all $x,y$.

I thought of using $$\langle E_\lambda (x+iy), x+iy\rangle = \langle E_\lambda x,x\rangle + \langle E_\lambda y,y\rangle - i \langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle + i \overline{\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle}$$
for all $x,y\in \mathcal H$, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks!

---

*Image for Reference:*
[image]

---

*Definition of Spectral Measure:*
[image]
Note that $$\nu(\triangle) := \langle E(\triangle)x,y\rangle$$ defines a complex valued measure $\nu$, and the notation $d\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle$ above is the same as $d\nu$.

Comment: $|B(x,y)|^{2} \leq B(x,x)B(y,y)$ for any bilinear functional $B$.

Comment: and where does that come from? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz inequality. Search the net and you will find a proof.

Comment: I found this: http://faculty.wwu.edu/curgus/Courses/Math_pages/Math_504/Cauchy-Schwarz-Bunyakovsky.html
It is clear that $\Phi(x,y)$ is a sesquilinear form. I do not think $\Phi$ is Hermitian and non-negative. These conditions are needed to apply the inequality. Could you explain some more? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: What exactly do you know about the $E_\lambda$? I.e., what is your definition of a spectral measure?

Comment: @PhoemueX I have added the definition in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not positive, then $\Phi$ will in general not be postive semi-definite, so that the Cauchy-Schwarz argument from the comments does not apply directly.

But one does not need positivity here. If $\Phi$ is a sesquilinear form on a complex vector space, then
$$
\Phi(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k \Phi(x+i^ky,x+i^ky).
$$
This is known as *polarization identity* and can be checked by direct, albeit tedious calculation.

If the underlying vector space is an inner product space and there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|\Phi(x,x)|\leq C\|x\|^2$, then
$$
|\Phi(x,y)|\leq\sum_{k=0}^3|\Phi(x+i^ky,x+i^ky)|\leq C\sum_{k=0}^3\|x+i^ky\|^2\leq 8C(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2).
$$
This implies that $\Phi$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, and you can use sesquilinearity to show that it is continuous at arbitrary $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have shown that $|\Phi(x,y)|$ is bounded for all $x,y$, which already completes the proof.